# precompile handlebar templates

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I'm wondering what's the best way to save precompiled handlebar templates and include them in an HTML file.

The site: http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html simply advises to call

> handlebars infile -f outfile

I put a template in a file and called the command. I got a JS file containing a function *program1* How would I now compile a second template? The sample at http://jsperf.com/jquery-template-vs-handlebars contains multiple functions named `program[1-9](...)` I assume they somehow must be generated.
Is it good advice to store precompiled templates at all?
I saw samples embedding script or link tags in an HTML file and traversing these and via AJAX loading the templates and compiling them dynamically.

Best,
Bernhard

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want multiple files, list them in the command like so

```
handlebars file1 file2 file3 -f outfile
```

You DO want to store precompiled files for your production site as it drastically cuts down on load time.

Answer (score 9):

You should use

```
handlebars /path/to/templates/*.handlebars -f /path/to/output/templates.js
```

Comment: I meanwhile stick to this command line: `handlebars [folder] -f [outfile].js -k [known helpers] -o -m` It works recursively. Templates in the subfolders are labeled respectively like so: `subfolder/templatename`

Comment: For completeness's sake `-o` ensures all used helpers are either built in or declared known. `-m` minimizes/uglifies the generated JavaScript https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/

Comment: For whatever reason when I try this sort of thing with `*.hbs` as the extension, I get a compiler error saying that it can't find `templates/*.hbs`. Piping individual files as from the other answer works, but it's tedious and error prone.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way, provided that you want to keep your templates with html extension is this:
handlebars   html

that is:
handlebars ./ -e html -f precompiled_templates.js