# How to load external html template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

**Given HTML code** such :

```
<!-- 2. Anchor -->
<div id="anchor">This div is the <b>#anchor</b>.</div>

<!-- 3. Template -->
<script id="tpl" type="text/template">
    {{#people}}
        <div><img src="{{photo}}"><b><a href="{{twitter}}">{{family}} {{name}}</a></b> — {{title}}, {{place}} : {{introduction}}.</div>
    {{/people}}
</script>
```

**Given JS/Handlebars** such as :

```
 <!--4. Handlebars.js slingshot -->
 //4a.function creation
 var slingshot = function (url, tplId, anchor) {
   $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
       var template = $(tplId).html();
       var stone = Handlebars.compile(template)(data);
       $(anchor).append(stone);
   });
 }

 slingshot('data.json', '#tpl', '#anchor'); // since url = 'data.json' , we can use both notations.
```

**How to externalize the my `3. Template` (#tpl) into a proper .txt text file (or other extension) ? How to load it back ?** so I may use the same template into various .html webpages.

Full code : http://bl.ocks.org/hugolpz/8075193 / http://bl.ocks.org/hugolpz/raw/8075193/

Answer (score 1):

Put the following template content into a file named test.handlebars

```
{{#people}}
    <div><img src="{{photo}}">
       <b>
         <a href="{{twitter}}">{{family}} {{name}}</a>
       </b> — {{title}},      
            {{place}} : {{introduction}}.
    </div>
{{/people}}
```

Write a function which will use the template as below

```
function getTemplate(name) {

if (Handlebars.templates === undefined || Handlebars.templates[name] === undefined) {
  $.ajax({
   url : name + ".handlebars",
   success : function(data) {
       if (Handlebars.templates === undefined) {
           Handlebars.templates = {};
       }
       Handlebars.templates[name] = Handlebars.compile(data);
   },
   async : false
 });
}
return Handlebars.templates[name];
 }
```

In the main program you can write the below statement to insert the template contents into div with id="anchor", as shown below

```
var Template = getTemplate("test")
this.$("#anchor).append(Template(data));
```

where data is the contents of a json file or some db query output which will give you the values meant for the following attributes in json format

people, twitter, name, family, photo, title, place, introduction

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you [have **already compiled** your template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10761622/802365). So you can use the technique I have described in [Bootstrapping Multiple Instances of an HandlebarsJS Template Into a Page](http://blog.edouard-lopez.com/bootstrapping-multiple-instances-of-an-handlebarsjs-template-into-a-page/).

#### Hook and libs

Place this in your `index.html`:

```
<div class="hook" data-json="data/whatever.json"></div>
```

and the JavaScript libs

```
<!-- Helper to inject data-set in templates instance -->
<script src="scripts/template-loader.js"></script>
<!-- Get the (compiled) template -->
<script src="scripts/myTemplate.hbs.js"></script>
```

#### template-loader.js helper

```
$(function(){
    'use strict';
    var compiledTemplate = myApp.Templates['app/templates/myTemplate.hbs'];

    $('.hook').each(function(i, h){              # h = current hook
        var url = $(h).data('json');             # data-set's url
        $.getJSON(url).then(function (json) {    # fetch data-set
            var tpl = compiledTemplate( json );  # inject data into template
            $(h).html(tpl);                      # inflate template in page
        });
    });
});
```

Please read the complete article for further details.